# How to avoid adding httpruntime tag to web.config at deploy

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, web-config, web-config-transform, httpruntime

I get the error `Config section 'System.web/httpRuntime' already defined` when I deploy our application to our development environment.

After deploying, if I push the `Authentication` button on the IIS servers management overview, I get the following error message:

[image: IIS server error message]

The `Web.Config` on the IIS has the `<system.web>` element looking like this:

```
<system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <authentication mode="None" />
    <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
    <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />
</system.web>
```

The problem is clearly that somehow both `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />` and `<httpRuntime requestValidationMode="4.5" />` are being added to `<system.web>`. My problem is that I can not figure out how the `<httpruntime>` tag is being added to my `Web.Config` when deployed to our development environment. It does not happen on my local machine. We use [Octopus Deploy](https://octopus.com/) as deployment tool (I'm not sure if that matters).

The `Web.Config` `<system.web>` in the project looks like this

```
<system.web>
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
</system.web>
```

and the `Web.Release.Config` `<system.web>`looks like this

```
 <system.web>
  <compilation xdt:Transform="RemoveAttributes(debug)" />

  <authentication xdt:Transform="Insert" mode="None" />

  <authorization xdt:Transform="Insert">
    <deny users="?" />
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

I'm not certain which parts of the project can have an influence on this so I'm adding in the following. Please let me know if I have left out any other relevant parts.

The solution consists of two project. A Web project and a Class Library. The Class Library project has this in the `app.config`:

```
<startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2"/>
</startup>
```

which I think might be causing some of the problem (based on [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2012/11/19/all-about-httpruntime-targetframework/)).

Comment: You can combine both of them in one httpRuntime element. `<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" requestValidationMode="4.5" />`

Comment: Thanks, but since I'm not the one putting the tag in, I don't have control of that (as far as I understand). The tag is added when I deploy.

Comment: First you need to check the the deployment logs. Web.config transformations are reported in the logs. Also if number of steps is large I would suggest to add manual intervention pauses between them and monitor when web.config is being changed.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about the logs. It turned out that somewhere in the deploy process packages were not being updated such that I, what ended up on the server, was actually the same file as the one I was trying to swap out.